# Where to find tnsnames.ora in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to find the tnsnames.ora file for my connections. My servers are hosted remotely i.e. I dont have it installed on my physcial system.

Answer (score 26):

SQL Developer looks for tnsnames.ora files in the following locations:

- your USER Home directory
- $ORACLE_HOME\network\admin -- assumes you have a client installed
- OS Environment Variable value for TNS_ADMIN
- Registry entry for TNS_ADMIN
- The location you specified in the preferences

[image]

The last one will trump the others.

You can see this for yourself in a SQL Worksheet, by running the command

```
show tns
```

[image]

You do not get a tnsnames.ora file 'for free.' Someone will need to build, maintain, and distribute one for and to you.

You can however connect to an Oracle Database without a TNSNames.ora file. Assuming you have all the information required (what's normally defined in the .ora file), you can make a 'Basic' connection.

[image]

Another quirk of the system - we actually read the entries in ANY file named tnsnames* - so if you have older versions of the file saved as something like tnsnames_old.ora or tnsnames.bak - we'll see and use those too, something SQL*Plus used to do and we were asked to follow as well.

Answer (score 0):

When using SQuirreL SQL, it is common to configure the connection details, including the service name, in the "tnsnames.ora" file. By placing the "tnsnames.ora" file within the project directory, it allows SQuirreL SQL to locate and use the connection details defined in that file for establishing database connections.

So, if you are working with SQuirreL SQL in a project and you have placed the "tnsnames.ora" file inside the project, it is likely because you want to ensure that SQuirreL SQL can easily access and use the connection details defined within that file for connecting to Oracle databases